# Is there a way to combine "Draggable links" with "Links to links"?

Tags: gojs

I am a newcommer to GoJS, I have been playing with it a bit and I was trying to have in my diagram links that can be linked to other links and at the same time they should be available in the palette.

The idea is have in the palette different kind of links (with different colors and meanings) that can be drag&drop into the diagram.

I have tried to mix the ["Dragabble Link"](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/draggableLink.html) and ["Links to links"](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/linksToLinks.html) examples from the documentation, mainly adding the "linkToLink" category to the link palette. I can drag&drop the link but it doens't have the "LinkLabel" in the middle to allow other links. Also the "labelKeys" array property is empty.

This is the code I use for the links initialization:

```
diagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("LinkLabel",
  $("Node",
    {
      selectable: false, avoidable: false,
      layerName: "Foreground"
    },
    $("Shape", "Ellipse",
      {
        width: 5, height: 5, stroke: null,
        portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer"
      })
  ));

diagram.linkTemplate = $(
  go.Link, // the whole link panel
  { relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true, reshapable: true },
  {
    routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
    curve: go.Link.JumpOver,
    corner: 5,
    toShortLength: 4
  },
  new go.Binding('points').makeTwoWay(),
  $(
    go.Shape, // the link path shape
    { isPanelMain: true, strokeWidth: 2 },
    new go.Binding('stroke', 'color')
  ),
  $(
    go.Shape, // the arrowhead
    { toArrow: '', stroke: null },
    new go.Binding('fill', 'color')
  )
);

diagram.linkTemplateMap.add(
  'Regular',
  $(
    go.Link, // the whole link panel
    { relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true, reshapable: true },
    {
      routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
      curve: go.Link.JumpOver,
      corner: 5,
      toShortLength: 4
    },
    new go.Binding('points').makeTwoWay(),
    $(
      go.Shape, // the link path shape
      { isPanelMain: true, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: 'black' }
    ),
    $(
      go.Shape, // the arrowhead
      { toArrow: '', stroke: null, fill: 'black' }
    )
  )
);

myDiagram.linkTemplateMap.add("linkToLink",
  $("Link",
    { relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true },
    $("Shape", { stroke: "#2D9945", strokeWidth: 2 }),
    new go.Binding('points').makeTwoWay(),
  ));

diagram.linkTemplateMap.add(
  'Marriage',
  $(
    go.Link,
    { relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true, reshapable: true },
    {
      routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
      curve: go.Link.JumpOver,
      corner: 5,
      toShortLength: 4
    },
    new go.Binding('points').makeTwoWay(),
    $(
      go.Shape,
      { isPanelMain: true, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: 'red' }
    ),
    $(
      go.Shape,
      { toArrow: '', stroke: null, fill: 'red' }
    )
  )
);

diagram.model =
  $(go.GraphLinksModel,
    { linkLabelKeysProperty: "labelKeys" });

diagram.toolManager.linkingTool.archetypeLabelNodeData =
  { category: "LinkLabel" };
```

And this is for the palette:

```
$(
  go.Palette,
  'myPaletteDiv',
  {
    nodeTemplateMap: diagram.nodeTemplateMap,
    linkTemplateMap: diagram.linkTemplateMap,
    model: new go.GraphLinksModel(
      [...],
      [
        {
          category: 'linkToLink',
          points: new go.List().addAll([
            new go.Point(0, 0),
            new go.Point(30, 0),
            new go.Point(30, 40),
            new go.Point(60, 40)
          ])
        },
        {
          category: 'Marriage',
          points: new go.List().addAll([
            new go.Point(0, 0),
            new go.Point(30, 0),
            new go.Point(30, 40),
            new go.Point(60, 40)
          ])
        }
      ]
    )
  }
);
```

I expected that dragging "linkToLinks" or "Marriage" into the diagram would display links allowing to be linked and not regular links. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should implement an "ExternalObjectsDropped" **DiagramEvent** listener (or augment one that you already have) to iterate over all of the newly dropped Parts and make sure each Link has a label Node, adding such a label Node if a Link doesn't have one.

The **LinkingTool.archetypeLabelNodeData** just specifies the node data to be copied as a new label Node when the user draws a new Link, so that property does not cover any Links created by the **DraggingTool**.

Comment: Hi @Walter, thank you for your help. I have been trying to implement your suggestion but I am struggling a bit. I have tried this:

`function dropped(e) {
  const link = e.subject.filter(part => part instanceof go.Link).first();

  if (link == null) {
    return;
  }

  e.diagram.model.addNodeData({
    category: "LinkLabel",
    labeledLink: link
  });
}`

I have attached the dropped function to the ExternalObjectsDropped DIagramEvent. However it adds the LinkLabel unrelated to the link. Am I doing something wrong about the labeledLink property?

Comment: I saw you already did something similar in here: https://forum.nwoods.com/t/integrate-link-to-link-into-dynamic-ports-diagram/11437/2

I think at the moment I have it working. Thank you!